# How to share methods among different JavaScript/Parse objects?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, ecmascript-6

This file defines the save/find methods for the `Document` object and exports it:

**store/document.js**

```
import Parse from 'parse'
import _ from 'lodash'

Parse.initialize('APP_ID', 'CLIENT_ID')

const Document = {}
const ParseDocument = Parse.Object.extend('Document')

Document.save = (json) => {
  const document = new ParseDocument()
  return document.save(json)
}

Document.find = () => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(ParseDocument)
  return query.find().then((results) =>
    _.map(results, (result) =>
      result.toJSON()
    )
  )
}

export default Document
```

This file uses the exported methods:

**views/documents.js**

```
submit () {
  const document = {
    title: this.title,
    content: this.content
  }
  Document.save(document).then(() =>
    Document.find().then((result) => /* DO STUFF */)
  )
}
```

This is fine if I have only one object. The problem is, I have many. For example I also have a `Section` object.

If I follow this pattern I would have to do this:

**store/section.js**

```
import Parse from 'parse'
import _ from 'lodash'

Parse.initialize('APP_ID', 'CLIENT_ID')

const Section = {}

...

Section.save = (json) => {
  const section = new ParseSection()
  return section.save(json)
}
```

How can I do it so I only have to write the `save` and `find` methods once, and use them, for example, like this `Document.save` and `Section.save`?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a facade object for each entity (subclass of Parse.Object):

**store/document.js**

```
'use strict'

const ParseFacade = require('./parse-facade')

const Document = new ParseFacade('Document')

module.exports = Document
```

**store/section.js**

```
'use strict'

const ParseFacade = require('./parse-facade')

const Section = new ParseFacade('Section')

module.exports = Section
```

**parse-facade.js**

```
'use strict'

const Parse = require('parse')
const _ = require('lodash')

Parse.initialize('APP_ID', 'CLIENT_ID')

function ParseFacade (className) {
    this.ParseObject = Parse.Object.extend(className)
}

ParseFacade.prototype.save = function save (json) {
    const PO = this.ParseObject
    const document = new PO()
    return document.save(json)
}

ParseFacade.prototype.find = function find () {
    const PO = this.ParseObject
    const query = new Parse.Query(PO)
    return query.find().then((results) =>
        _.map(results, (result) => result.toJSON()))
}

module.exports = ParseFacade
```

To add functionality to a given entity, add a property as usual:

```
Document.doSomething = function doSomething (...args) {
    // this.ParseObject refers to the subclassed Parse.Object
    // ...
}
```